# add-on domain path without main domain path in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, addon-domain

In my hosting account on cpanel, I have one main domain for e.g. www.abc.com and one addon domain say xyz.com. The document root of addon domain is home/public_html/xyz.com. So the .htaccess file in root directory of abc.com is the main htaccess file. (no another .htaccess file for addon domain). The problem is xyz.com is automatically redirected to www.abc.com/xyz.com. I have set 301 redirection only for www.abc.com (for non-www to www). 
I want when I type xyz.com it is redirect as www.xyz.com. not as www.abc.com/xyz.com

Comment: Can you show content of both .htaccess files?